# Minimax algorithm for Othello not working correctly

Tags: java, minimax

```
public class OthelloJPlayer extends OthelloPlayer {
  @Override
  public OthelloMove getMove(OthelloState state) {
    int bestchoice = 0;
    int bestscore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    boolean maximizingPlayer = true;

    // generate the list of moves:
    List<OthelloMove> moves = state.generateMoves();

    if (moves.isEmpty()) {
      // If there are no possible moves, just return "pass":
      return null;
    } else {
      // turn moves to states
      List<OthelloState> states = new ArrayList<OthelloState>();

      for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++) {
        states.add(state.applyMoveCloning(moves.get(i)));
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
        // uses minmax to determine best move.
        int score = (MinMax(3, states.get(i), maximizingPlayer));

        if (score > bestscore) {
          bestscore = score;
          bestchoice = i;

        }
      }
    }

    return moves.get(bestchoice);
  }

  // min max algorithm
  public int MinMax(int depth, OthelloState game_board, boolean maximizingPlayer) {
    List<OthelloMove> moves;

    if (depth == 0) {
      int score = game_board.score();

      return score;
    }

    if (maximizingPlayer) {
      int bestvalue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      // gets other players moves
      moves = game_board.generateMoves(1);

      if (moves.isEmpty()) {
        int score = game_board.score();

        return score;

      } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++) {
          OthelloState new_game_board = new OthelloState(8);
          new_game_board = game_board.applyMoveCloning(moves.get(i));

          int returned_score = MinMax(depth - 1, new_game_board, false);
          bestvalue = max(bestvalue, returned_score);
        }
      }
      return bestvalue;
    } else {
      int bestvalue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      // gets your moves
      moves = game_board.generateMoves(0);

      if (moves.isEmpty()) {
        int score = game_board.score();

        return score;
      } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < moves.size(); i++) {
          OthelloState new_game_board = new OthelloState(8);
          new_game_board = game_board.applyMoveCloning(moves.get(i));

          int returned_score = MinMax(depth - 1, new_game_board, true);
          bestvalue = min(bestvalue, returned_score);
        }
      }

      return bestvalue;
    }
  }
}
```

My minimax algorithms does not appear to be returning the most optimal move. When my agent that uses  minimax agent plays against an agent that performs random moves sometimes it looses. from my perceptive everything looks okay could someone please check my logic I must be missing something. The heuristic is the score. a positive score means you are winning a negative score means the other player is winning.

Comment: See this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511814/minimax-algorithm-doesnt-return-best-move

Comment: In a game with a branching factor as high as this one, you can usually explore only a few levels ahead in the tree. Therefore suboptimal moves can be made. In no way Minimax (with or without prunning) could avoid this. The only moves guaranteed to be optimal are those when the bottom of the tree is "visible", usually at the end of the game.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues.

1. Your `getMove` method is really the root of the search, and it's a max node. Therefore, it should invoke `MinMax` with `maximizingPlayer = false`.
2. When you invoke `MinMax`, you need to swap players. Right now, you just go from max -> max -> min -> min -> min... since you use `true` and `false` constants. Change your invocation (for both the min and max cases) to `MinMax(depth - 1, new_game_board, !maximizingPlayer)`.
3. Make sure that `game_board.score()` gives an evaluation from the perspective of the max player.